# Updating a many-to-many relation using GraphDiff cause an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, graphdiff

I'm using `EF code first 6.1` with `.NET 4` in my application and have following classes in my model(I cut other unrelated parts of diagram. e.g `Permission` has other navigations):
[image]

My business logic works with detached entities so I'm using `RefactorThis.GraphDiff 2.0.1.0` to perform updates. 
I want to update an `applicationUserInApplication` object, so I get an existing `applicationUserInApplication` with its `SecurityRole`s from database and return it as a `View-Model` then update it and map back it to `applicationUserInApplication` using `Automapper` (in update operation, I only change `SecurityRoles` collection of an `applicationUserInApplication` , these `SecurityRole`s saved before and I only select them), so I defined following configuration:

```
_dbContext.UpdateGraph(appUserInApplication, map => map
                .OwnedCollection(t => t.SecurityRoles, with=>
                                 with.AssociatedCollection(t=>t.Permissions)
                                     .AssociatedEntity(t => t.ApplicationDescriptor))
                .AssociatedEntity(t=>t.ApplicationDescriptor)
                .AssociatedEntity(t=>t.AppUser)
                .AssociatedEntity(t=>t.UserProfile));
```

and defined following mapping for `AppUserInApplication` in `AppUserInApplication_Mapping` class:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.AppUser).WithMany(t => t.AppUserInApplications).HasForeignKey(d => d.AppUserId);
this.HasRequired(t => t.Applicationdescriptor).WithMany(t => t.AppUserInApplications).HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicationId);
this.HasMany(t => t.SecurityRoles).WithMany(t => t.AppUserInApplications)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("AppUserInApplicationSecurityRole");
                m.MapLeftKey("AppUserInApplications_Id");
                m.MapRightKey("SecurityRoles_Id");
            });
this.HasRequired(t => t.UserProfile).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>t.UserProfileId);
```

After calling above `UpdateGraph()`, when I call `_dbContext.SaveChange();` I get following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

**[Updated]**

I also, tried following mapping

```
_dbContext.UpdateGraph(appUserInApplication, map => map
           .AssociatedCollection(t => t.SecurityRoles)
           .AssociatedEntity(t => t.Application)
           .AssociatedEntity(t => t.UserProfile)
           .AssociatedEntity(t => t.AppUser);
```

But I get same error, yet.

Does anyone know where is the problem?

**[Updated]**

I uploaded a simplified version of my model, you can get it from https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9dvrb6ebd5wo7h/GraphdiffTest.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception means that Entity Framework is complaining about navigation properties you've mapped as required but not set (they're null). After debugging your sample code, this was the case for all of your navigation properties except security roles.

If you change your code like this:

[image: working code]

The navigation properties are set and everything works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your code and I think that the problem is in your mappings. AppUserInApplication table has a Many-To-Many relation with table SecurityRoles, and in your mappings you used "OwnedCollection" - which should be used in One-To-Many or One-To-One relations, try to use the AssociatedCollection instead.

```
  _dbContext.UpdateGraph(appUserInApplication, map => map
            .AssociatedCollection(t => t.SecurityRoles, with=> (....)
```

Comment: The `AssociatedCollection` does not have 2nd paramneter(`with => ...`), but I used it too(without 2nd parameter), the problem didn't solved.(I updated the question)